# Unable to update build in Google cloud Platform?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am trying to update my builds in gcloud platform, but after running command in terminal gcloud app `deploy --version myApp-subset-000000`. It's throw error,

> Updating service [default]...failed.
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build
> 6ccc9106-db28-4d26-b57c-18ea83a7c544 status: FAILURE Build error
> details: Build error details not available.

Comment: Can you share more? Your runtime, the app specificity, the app.yaml file, your region...

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your concern? Have you checked the cloud build history? If so, are there more information there? Does this worked before? If so, did you change something?

Comment: Samuel Romero, after opening the build link it's show no permission to check the issue..
**You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page** project name cloudbuild.builds.get

Comment: It is a bit difficult to know the reason why that is happening if you cannot access to the builds page... Have you tried to use the verbosity flag? Something like gcloud app deploy -- version myApp-subset-000000 --verbosity=debug? This could show more details about the error.